# Non Homogeneous Heat Equation Solution Verification and Properties

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to independently learn about PDEs following Evans' text. It is shown (Theorem 2, page 50) that for $f (t,x) \in C^{1,2}\left([0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d\right)$ with compact support, a solution to the non-homogeneous heat equation
$$\Delta u - u_t = f(x,t)$$ is given by
$$u(x,t) = \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(s, y) e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4(t-s)}}{(4\pi(t-s))^{-1/2}} dy ds$$
and the proof in the text makes sense. However, I have seen that $f$ may be more general - in fact, it may be taken to be Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and compact support.  In this case, $u$ given as above still solves the PDE, and additionally, $u, u_t, \partial u /\partial x_i, \partial^2 u /\partial x_i \partial x_j$ are all also Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha$.  Where can I find a good/readable coverage of the proof of this result?

Comment: Maybe a density argument?

Comment: What does a density argument mean?

Comment: Is $C^{1,2}$ dense in the Holder class?

Comment: $C^{1,2}$ is dense in the set of continuous functions, so yes, we can approximate a Holder continuous $f$ with some functions $f_n$ which converge to $f$ and obtain corresponding PDE solutions $u_n$, but how do you guarantee convergence of the $u_n$ in an appropriate sense to some $u$ for which the derivatives satisfy the Holder continuity condition?